# Sonarlint:Unable to connect to the sonarbaquue server with Intelliji after adding ssl certificate to the JVM keystore

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am trying to connect to the sonarbaeque server using Sonarlint and  get the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error 503 on http://****.****.****.****:portNumber
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.SonarLintWsClient.handleError(SonarLintWsClient.java:146)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.SonarLintWsClient.get(SonarLintWsClient.java:87)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.validate.ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.lambda$fetchServerInfos$0(ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.java:97)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.SonarLintWsClient.processTimed(SonarLintWsClient.java:226)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.validate.ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.fetchServerInfos(ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.java:96)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.validate.ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.checkVersionAndStatus(ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.java:60)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.validate.ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.checkVersionAndStatus(ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.java:50)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.WsHelperImpl.validateConnection(WsHelperImpl.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.WsHelperImpl.validateConnection(WsHelperImpl.java:58)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.tasks.ConnectionTestTask.run(ConnectionTestTask.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:932)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:482)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$new$0(ProgressRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$null$3(ProgressRunner.java:233)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:627)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The thing is I already added the certificate to the JVM keystore in the same way i did to settings.xml file in the Maven root folder and .m2 folder and they worked well. But for the Sonarlint this was not the case